# Configurable swatch not available in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, swatches

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.1.1 in here Configurable swatch not available in backend. I follow this for configurable swatch `http://www.venustheme.com/configurable-swatches-guide-for-magento-1-9-1/`

I don't know what is the problem

[image]

Comment: Check Mage_ConfigurableSwatches module, is enable or not ?

Comment: No such Module....

Comment: check ConfigurableSwatches  module on this path : app/code/core/Mage/

Comment: Thanks it's working module is there but no xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_ConfigurableSwatches>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
                <Mage_CatalogSearch />
            </depends>
        </Mage_ConfigurableSwatches>
    </modules>
</config>
```

save it as `app/etc/modules/Mage_ConfigurableSwatches.xml`  after Logout and login then see it's there or not